# 14.04 server glib critcal: source id x

Tags: 14.04, server, glib, console-kit

Console keeps giving me this error

glib critcal: source id x  was not found when attempting to remove it

I don't know why it gives me this.  If someone could give me some log to give ill post it?

Srry for the lack of information.

Edit:

I figured out that purging console kit fixes this but i dont really know what it is for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that purging console kit fixes this error